# view one point in different positions

Tags: matlab, position, point, figure

We want to show a point  "called type1" in different positions (2,8,..), we used this code:

```
x = linspace(0,30,1000);
axis([0,20,-0.4,1.5]);
ax = gca;
h = hgtransform('Parent',ax);
type1=plot(x(1)-1,y(1),'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','red','MarkerSize',20);
type2=plot(x(1)-1,y(1),'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','green','MarkerSize',40);
type1.XData= 2;
hold on
type2.XData= 6;
hold on
type1.XData= 8;
```

But only the last position is showed

How to keep each showed point viewed in the figure??

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Rather than changing the `XData` you will need to create a *new* plot with each different value of x if you want to see the old ones.

Comment: @Suever we want the points to be showed in the same figure (without opening a new figure) shouldn't this be done using hold on??

Comment: `hold on` works *if you have separate plot objects you want to show*. If you modify the `XData` position you are changing an existing plot so `hold on` has no effect there. You will want a `hold on` between the two calls to `plot` so that they are both shown though.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `hold on` is to allow you to have multiple plot objects on the same axes. So you will want a `hold on` statement between your two `plot` calls to ensure that they are both shown.

```
type1 = plot(x(1)-1,y(1),'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','red','MarkerSize',20);
hold on
type2 = plot(x(1)-1,y(1),'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','green','MarkerSize',40);
```

Now, when you change the `XData` property of one of these plots, that is modifying an existing plot object, and the old `XData` value is not going to be visible (`hold on` doesn't have anything to do with the *contents* of the plots, just the plot objects themselves).

If you want to plot multiple x values, you *could* create additional plot objects (one for each x position).

```
plot(2, y(1))
plot(6, y(1))
plot(8, y(1))
```

A better way is just to plot *all* the points up front in your initial `plot` commands.

```
plot(x, y, 's', 'Parent', h, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerSize', 20);
hold on
plot(x, y, 's', 'Parent', h, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g', 'MarkerSize', 40);
```

Comment: @ Suever now we can show the points, if these points were referring to car types, how can we move these points in a train randomly ?

Comment: @user3332603 what do you mean Randomly?

Comment: @ Suever we have an array contains 100 random numbers between 1:5 (referring to 5 types of points/cars) we need to move these points in a train sequentially with a gap between each two cars

Comment: @user3332603 So what are the places where you set the `XData` in your post? Are those the 5 cars?

Comment: @ Suever we have a new code how can we show it to you?

Comment: You can edit your original question to be more clear and show the actual code